# A column returns null value in SQL statement containing multiple SELECTs

Tags: mysql, sql

I inherited a particular code from a previous developer. I intend to build the application all over again, but I have to add some functionalities before I proceed.

Firstly, It's a 62 column table that has to do with accounting, and I also have to fetch values from different tables with a single call to get the values that I need before insertion.

Lets say I need to make an insertion into table `dailysales` and i need to get values from table `a,b,c` and `d` at the same time.
I already have an sql statement for fetching this values, and it works fine except that a particular column keeps returning as `NULL`.
Here's my code:

```
SELECT `gds_pnr_ref`, `transaction_date`,
       (SELECT `lastname` FROM `a` WHERE `id` = `staff` LIMIT 1) as `lastname`,
       (SELECT `firstname` FROM `a` WHERE `id` = `staff` LIMIT 1) as `firstname`,
       (SELECT `department_name` FROM `b` WHERE `id` = `staff_department` LIMIT 1) as `department`,
       (SELECT `name` FROM `b` WHERE `memo_serial` = '$some_value' LIMIT 1) as `pax_name`,
       (SELECT `customer_name` FROM `c` WHERE `id` = `customer_name` LIMIT 1) as `customer`,
       travel_product,
       (SELECT `vendor_name` FROM `c` WHERE `id` = `vendor` LIMIT 1) as `vendor` 
FROM `d` WHERE `id` = '$some_value' LIMIT 1
```

The column `(SELECT customer_name FROM c WHERE id = customer_name LIMIT 1) as customer` always returns as `NULL` but when i run it independently it gives me the appropriate value.

I'm very much opened to a better solution for going about this.

Comment: `id` = `customer_name`? I expect a number on `id` and a string on `customer_name`. So they can't be equal.

Comment: Have you tried using joins instead of subquery?? You should post your tables structure

Comment: *It's a 62 column table* is that me, or that smells?

Comment: could you show me an example of using joins for up to, lets say 4 tables

Comment: `staff`, `staff_department`, `customer_name` and `vendor` are all columns of table `d`

Comment: and yes, `id` is an integer and `customer_name` is a string. That is how the table was set even though their values are the same. So is that why ?

Comment: Wow, your table name is a,b,c,d?

Comment: no they are not. It's just for the sake of asking the question

Comment: @Cid Welcome to accounting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys, but this is the query i finally went with that returns all my needed values with non as null.

```
SELECT  `a`.`currency`, 
        `a`.`vendor_name`,
        CONCAT(`c`.`lastname`, ' ', `c`.`firstname`) AS `actioned_by`,
        `e`.`department_name` AS `department`,
        `f`.`customer_name` AS `customer`,
        `g`.`currency_name` AS `fl_currency`,
        `b`.`name`,
        `b`.`nuc`,
        `b`.`tax`,
        `b`.`comm` AS `comm_percen`,
        `b`.`comm_tax` AS `comm_tax_value`,
        `b`.`actual_comm`,
        `b`.`service_charge`,
        `b`.`dip`,
        SUM(`b`.`vendor`) AS payable,
        `b`.`charge` AS receivable
FROM ((((((`d`
INNER JOIN `b` ON `d`.`id` = `b`.`memo_serial`)
INNER JOIN `a` ON `d`.`vendor` = `a`.`id`)
INNER JOIN `c` ON `d`.`staff` = `c`.`id`) 
INNER JOIN `e` ON `d`.`staff_department` = `e`.`id`) 
INNER JOIN `f` ON `d`.`customer_name` = `f`.`id`) 
INNER JOIN `g` ON `a`.`currency` = `g`.`id`)  WHERE `d`.`id` = '$some_value'
```

Using sub queries had some limitations, like when i needed to pull out multiple entries of the a particular foreign key in a particular table. It keeps returning the first row value only. So i ended up using `INNER JOIN` to pull from 6 different tables to get my results and it's way neater

Answer (score 3):

You should *always* qualify column names in a query.  Presumably, you intend something like this:

```
SELECT d.`gds_pnr_ref`, d.`transaction_date`,
       (SELECT a.`lastname` FROM `a` WHERE a.`id` = d.`staff` LIMIT 1) as `lastname`,
       (SELECT a.`firstname` FROM `a` WHERE a.`id` = d.`staff` LIMIT 1) as `firstname`,
       (SELECT b.`department_name` FROM `b` WHERE b.`id` = d.`staff_department` LIMIT 1) as `department`,
       (SELECT b.`name` FROM `b` WHERE b.`memo_serial` = ? LIMIT 1) as `pax_name`,
       (SELECT c.`customer_name` FROM `c` WHERE c.`id` = d.`customer_name` LIMIT 1) as `customer`,
       d.travel_product,
       (SELECT c.`vendor_name` FROM `c` WHERE c.`id` = d.`vendor` LIMIT 1) as `vendor` 
FROM `d`
WHERE d.`id` = ?
LIMIT 1;
```

I have to guess where the columns come from -- so this might not be 100% correct.

Notice that I also replaced the string variables with the `?` placeholder.  This is a reminder that you should be using parameters for such values.

Comment: okay, thank you. But is it possible that it can be done using the `JOIN` statement

Comment: @Devops-Paddy . . . This answers the question that you asked.  Your query is reasonable, so there is not a need to rewrite it once you have fixed the logic problem in the subquery (by using aliases).  If you have another question, ask it as a *new* question.